# Nothing shows up when i click my Navigation drawer menu options?

Tags: java, android

I have  used json file and display it but when I click on navigation drawer menu a blank page opens but no content is displayed. In the same application I have used Json and displayed the content for the second case. But it doesnt work for this one. Any help would be appriciated

```
public class NewNewsMain extends SherlockFragment {

      private ListView listedView;
      ArrayList<NewNews> newsList;
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_newnews, container, false);
         listedView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listed);
         newsList= new ArrayList<>();
    new NewsAsynctask().execute("http://www.thebritishcollege.edu.np/api/news");
    return rootView;

}
public class NewsAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {


        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {

                HttpEntity entities = response.getEntity();
                String datas = EntityUtils.toString(entities);

                JSONObject jObje = new JSONObject(datas);
                JSONArray jArrays = jObje.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArrays.length(); i++) {
                    NewNews newss = new NewNews();

                    JSONObject jRealsobject = jArrays.getJSONObject(i);

                    newss.setTitle(jRealsobject.getString("title"));
                 //   news.setThumbnail(jRealsobject.getString("thumbnail"));
                    newsList.add(newss);
                }
                return true;

            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result==true){

            NewNewsAdapter adapters= new NewNewsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.newnews, newsList);
            listedView.setAdapter(adapters);
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by adding `notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

```
NewNewsAdapter adapters = new NewNewsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.newnews, newsList);
listedView.setAdapter(adapters);
adapters.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also make sure the response is not null by printing a simple log.

Comment: Ok will try this one and will catch up with you tomorrow. my other question is when u work with a news app  navigation drawer has  menu called sports, regional, current affairs . will the above code work lets say for sports? is there anything else to be written in manifest file apart from internet:uses permission? i need to create an application which has navigation 3 drawer and displays information from 3 separate JSON files one for each.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried printing the JSON values?